# Aggregating duplicates post UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the feeling there might be a shorter way of querying the following.

This structure is repeated in several stored procedures.
I do a `CROSS JOIN` between the target elements of a table and the DimDate view - with 0 for each measure. Then `UNION` the results with the actual results. Then in the outer query it is all aggregated in case of duplicates.

Is there a more efficient way of going about this?

```
SELECT Name,
       DateKey,
       Measure1 = SUM(Measure1),
       Measure2 = SUM(Measure2)
FROM (
    SELECT  Name,
        DateKey,
        Measure1 = SUM(Measure1),
        Measure2 = SUM(Measure2)
    FROM    WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data
    GROUP BY SearchName,
        DateKey
    UNION 
    SELECT  Name,   
        d.DateKey,
        0,
        0
    FROM    WH.dbo.vw_DimDate d
        CROSS JOIN
        WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data a  
    WHERE   d.DayMarker >= CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(6),DATEADD(MM,-24,GETDATE()),112) + '01',112)
    GROUP BY a.Name,    
        d.DateKey
    ) x
GROUP BY Name,
    DateKey
```

Comment: Are the `name` values only stored on `WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data`, or is there a reference table anywhere?

Comment: @MarkBannister not too sure it makes a difference; I'm interested to see both possibilities - although initially without a reference table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a left outer join.  It might not look simpler but it would be easier for the database to evaluate than a UNION.

```
SELECT x.Name,
       x.DateKey,
       Measure1 = SUM(sum_table.Measure1),
       Measure2 = SUM(sum_table.Measure2)
FROM (SELECT distinct Name, d.DateKey
      FROM    WH.dbo.vw_DimDate d, WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data a  
      WHERE   d.DayMarker >= CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(6),DATEADD(MM,-24,GETDATE()),112) + '01',112)) x
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data sum_table
    ON x.Name = sum_table.Name AND x.DateKey = sum_table.DateKey
GROUP BY x.Name, x.DateKey
```

Note, that this assumes that every value you need in WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data will be in the cross join.  Otherwise you need a full outer join instead of a left outer join.

Comment: Note that the use of distinct rather than group by was stylistic, since I thought it would be a more succinct statement.

Comment: I'm a little uncertain if the sum will return nulls instead of zeros.  That might have to be tweaked.

Comment: +1 `L.O.J` is a definite improvement over `UNION`. I've not see that cross join syntax before .... just use a `.` ?

Comment: Yep.  It's the old syntax for joins.  The From clause listed tables, and if there was no where clause to limit the results it was a cross join.

Comment: Comma, not period for the cross join.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if it's more efficient, but you could try only doing `GROUP BY` / `SUM` only once in your query.

```
SELECT Name,
       DateKey,
       Measure1 = SUM(Measure1),
       Measure2 = SUM(Measure2)
FROM (
    SELECT  SearchName AS Name,
            DateKey,
            Measure1,
            Measure2
    FROM    WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT
            Name,   
            d.DateKey,
            0,
            0
    FROM    WH.dbo.vw_DimDate d
            CROSS JOIN WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data a  
    WHERE   d.DayMarker >= CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(6),DATEADD(MM,-24,GETDATE()),112) + '01',112)
    ) x
GROUP BY Name,
         DateKey
```

Comment: I could see still needing to have the `GROUP BY` in the second `SELECT` of the `UNION` just so that there's only one row per Name and DateKey.

Comment: @JasonWhisman Added `DISTINCT` -- although I think that's identical to a `GROUP BY` since there are no aggregates in the subquery.

Comment: Yeah, it should have the same effect.

Comment: +1 Good point - why am I bothering with the `SUM`'s in the subquery!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got this exactly right since I don't have a structure to work with but this might be more efficient.  It's using a UNION ALL which is always more efficient than a UNION.  It's able to do this because the first part of the UNION is grouped (no duplicates) and the second part is checking the first part to make sure it doesn't have any duplicates.  The only reason I question the efficiency is because the first part of the UNION may have to be run twice.

```
WITH DataResults (
SELECT  Name,
    DateKey,
    Measure1 = SUM(Measure1),
    Measure2 = SUM(Measure2) 
FROM    WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data
GROUP BY SearchName,
    DateKey
    )
SELECT * FROM DataResults
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT Name,   
    d.DateKey,
    0,
    0
FROM    WH.dbo.vw_DimDate d
CROSS JOIN WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data a  
WHERE   d.DayMarker >= CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(6),DATEADD(MM,-24,GETDATE()),112) + '01',112)
  -- Check for existence within the upper part o fthe union.
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DataResults 
            WHERE a.Name = DataResults.Name -- I'm making an assumption here that name is in tb_r12028dxi_Data.  You didn't say.
              AND d.DateKey = DataResults.DateKey )
GROUP BY a.Name,    
    d.DateKey
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the alternative - lots of "syntactic sugar" - I've not checked but I suspect the execution plan will be quite similar to my existing query

Comment: Actually I would be surprised if the execution plans are the same.  The CTE is there so that I can check for existence in the initial query. That, among other things, allows me to use a UNION ALL instead of a UNION which doesn't require a sort.

Comment: cheers Kenneth - I'll test all the possibilities and if I have time will reply back with results

Answer (score 0):

A variation on pswg's approach - I think this *may* be more efficient:

```
SELECT Name,
       DateKey,
       Measure1 = SUM(Measure1),
       Measure2 = SUM(Measure2)
FROM (SELECT SearchName AS Name,
             DateKey,
             Measure1,
             Measure2
      FROM   WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data
      UNION 
      SELECT Name,   
             d.DateKey,
             0,
             0
      FROM   WH.dbo.vw_DimDate d
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM WH.dbo.tb_r12028dxi_Data) a  
      WHERE d.DayMarker >= CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(6),DATEADD(MM,-24,GETDATE()),112) + '01',112)
     ) x
GROUP BY Name, DateKey
```